# How to get Django 1.7 working on Ubuntu 14.04 with nginx and virtualenv using python 2.7 while having python 3.4 installed?

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

I am a newbie to Django and Python installation. Intermediate with Ubuntu 14.04.

These are my installations so far in my Ubuntu 14.04.

```
apt-get install python3-setuptools --force-yes -y ## for python3
easy_install3 pip ## for python3
apt-get install python-setuptools --force-yes -y ## for python2.7 or above
easy_install pip ## for python2.7 or above
apt-get install python-dev --force-yes -y ## because ubuntu 14.04 does not have dev version of python 2
apt-get install python3-dev --force-yes -y ## because ubuntu 14.04 does not have dev version of python 3.4
apt-get install links --force-yes -y ##a command line web browser
apt-get install python-flup --force-yes -y ## connects python to uwsgi)

apt-get install build-essential --force-yes -y ## 

pip2 install django uwsgi virtualenv ## use pip to install django and uwsgi and virtualenv for python2
pip3 install django uwsgi  ## use pip to install django and uwsgi for python3
```

For the full list, please look at https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/41c55e0c08eda42e2cb3#file-install-sh-L88

I am confused about the use of `virtualenv`.

I want to prepare my ubuntu 14.04 server edition for a production level of Django 1.7 as much as possible.

The reason why I installed multiple Python environment because I may have other Python apps running which require 3.4.

My Django files are from bitbucket repository and I have git cloned them into `/var/virtual/WebApps/DjangoProject`

Inside `/var/virtual/WebApps/DjangoProject`, I have manage.py and other files and folders.

Please advise on how do I get the Django project running for this situation.

I am currently testing this setup on my virtualbox and vagrant.

**EDIT**

There will be at least 2 Django applications. 1 requires 2.7 python. The other requires 3.4 python.

Let me add that this is a single server that will host the application, frontend, and database.

**EDIT 1**

I have restarted with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and I started with Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.4.0.

I then did `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv` which I checked its version: `1.11.4`.

I have created `~/virtualenvs/py2.7` and `~/virtualenvs/py3.4`.

Inside `~/virtualenvs`, I did `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 py2.7`
and  `~/virtualenvs`, I did `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3.4`

So how do I install python2 only libraries for the python 2 app?

E.g. are `django-adminfiles`, `sorl-thumbnail`, `psycopg2`

**EDIT 5**

Use `virtualenv --system-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python2 py2.7` instead

Answer (score 4):

> I have restarted with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and I started
>   with Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.4.0.

Okay, so now in your system you have two **base versions** of Python. Base version just means, the versions that are supported by your operating system; which you have installed globally.

In other words you have installed them using the operating system's package installers *and did not compile them separately*.

In practice, this above only matters in Linux, because in Windows you cannot install "locally" without going through a few hoops; all Python installers will register themselves in the registry thus making them global, base Python versions.

> I then did sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv which I checked its
>   version: 1.11.4.

This package is outdated (current version is [`12.0.7`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)).

Now you have virtual environment installed against the *base Python 2* version because the [package requires Python 2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-virtualenv).

In practical terms it means if you need to upgrade Python 2, you'll have to make sure `python-virtualenv` is also updated for the base versions of both Pythons that are supported by your operating system. This means, when you `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, `virtualenv` will be upgraded.

Usually this doesn't matter as its a rare case if `python2` is upgraded and then `python-virtualenv` is not upgraded to match its dependency.

However this is not recommended because you want to control the versions of critical software "manually" to avoid any surprises. There are ways to control this on Ubuntu and other debian-like distributions by [pinning versions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto); but even if you do so, you may not be getting the latest version of the library which may force you later on to *uninstall* the version that came with your operating system, and reinstall it from source.

> I have created ~/virtualenvs/py2.7 and ~/virtualenvs/py3.4.
>
> Inside ~/virtualenvs, I did virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 py2.7 and 
>   ~/virtualenvs, I did virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3.4
>
> So how do I install python2 only libraries for the python 2 app?
>
> E.g. are django-adminfiles, sorl-thumbnail, psycopg2

In order for `solr-thumbnail` and `psycopg2` to be installed correctly, you need to build their dependencies; so

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev 
sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++-dev libboost-python1.55-dev
sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev libpython-dev libpython3-dev libssl-dev libpq-dev
```

To install libraries for the Python 2 app:

1. Activate the virtual environment; by typing `source ~/virtualenvs/py2.7/bin/activate`
2. Type `pip install _____` (name of the library)

---

To support multiple Python applications with different major versions; your system should have both Python major versions installed (you already have done this).

You then install virtualenv for each Python major version.  You can skip this step if your applications are fully contained (that is, they include the Python runtime required - but this is a rare case) or if you have a single purpose server.

You should avoid installing anything but the base Python libraries in your system's global python. That is avoid (as root, or using sudo) to `pip install` things; because these will be installed for all users of Python and may cause problems (on some systems; like Fedora/RedHat - critical system packages like `yum` rely on the base system Python).

Next step is to make sure you have a suitable build environment available.  This means for Debian-sourced systems to install `build-essential` and further the support libraries for common Python drivers and modules.  The exact libraries you need to install will depend on the applications you are planning to host, but at a minimum you should make sure `PIL` (or `Pillow`) can be installed and database drivers' support libraries are available. To do so, you can `apt-get build-deb python-imaging psycopg2 python-mysqldb` (for PostgreSQL, MySQL and PIL).

Now you have a system ready to support most Python applications. You can then optionally add other utilities, but I would try to avoid assuming too much about what applications will require.

To host an app:

1. Create a virtual environment with the base version of Python required. So virtualenv-2.7 or virtualenv-3 as the normal non-root user account.
2. Install required packages into the virtual environment.
3. Adjust the bootstrap script for your application to use the correct Python binary. This is usually done from whatever process you are using to manage your application server. For example, on my server I use `supervisord`.

That's all you have to do. Everything else will depend on the individual application's requirements and setup (so if you need to serve static files, you'll have to configure that mapping, etc.)

---

After reading your [shell script](https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/1781035db3ee7b6cddc9#file-install-sh-L88), it seems you are trying to build a server that will support both the application, the front end and the database.

In order to support such a system; you will need to install the following:

1. Database server(s) that you would like to support. As this is a single purpose server, you will also need to install database command line clients.
2. Source code tools (`git`, etc.)
3. A global process manager (like [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) or [`circus`](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/0.11.1/)).
4. Base Python versions you intend to support; and their development headers (`sudo apt-get install python-dev`)
5. [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/12.0.5), [`pip`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing.html#pip-included-with-python), and then [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html). These tools should be **installed from source** rather than your package manager; to ensure the latest versions are installed. You should install these globally (ie, as root) so they are available for all users.
6. A build tool chain (ie, "Development Tools" or `build-essential`)
7. Support libraries for any extensions (but not the extensions themselves). The easiest way to do this is to use the package manager to build the dependencies and not the packages `sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging psycopg2 python-mysqldb`.

The next thing you need to do is decide how you will run your application servers (the "django code"). You can use `uwsgi`, `gunicorn`, etc. as these are the ones most tested with django.

You need to be able to support multiple versions of these runtimes, so instead of installing them globally across the system; just build their dependencies and install the specific version required for each application in its own isolated environment.

The next thing you need to install is a front end proxy for your applications. You can install whatever proxy suits your needs (nginx is the most popular); but please **install from source** rather than the packages as those are almost always out of date.

Once all this is setup, the process of hosting a django application is the following:

1. Create a separate user account with a non-login shell.
2. Create a virtual environment in this user's home directory. I recommend keeping some standard here, like `env` for the virtual environments.
3. Download/copy the source code of your application.
4. Create a standard directory where you will store the static files. For example I use `$HOME/www/static`.
5. Create an entry in your process manager.
6. Create an entry in your proxy for front end routing.
7. Reload your proxy server.
8. Reload your process manager.

You can automate/script a lot of the above. For example, you can create a  [custom skeleton directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29010/gkhqx.html#usersetup-52714) to create the base directories for you when adding new users; and you can create custom templates for other areas using tools like [`cookiecutter`](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter).

Comment: "You should avoid installing anything but the base Python libraries" I use root and I use pip2 and pip3 instead. Does that count as avoiding?

Comment: " at a minimum you should make sure PIL (or Pillow) can be installed and database drivers' support libraries are available. To do so, you can apt-get build-deb python-imaging psycopg2 python-mysqldb (for PostgreSQL, MySQL and PIL)." I use pip2 install psycopg2 and as for postgres and mysql, I did this https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/41c55e0c08eda42e2cb3#file-install-sh-L77 Is that okay?

Comment: "Create a virtual environment with the base version of Python required. So virtualenv-2.7 or virtualenv-3 as the normal non-root user account." Can you elaborate with the exact command lines? So far, i run `pip2 install virtualenv` using root user account. Do I need to undo this?

Comment: 1. No, but there are some packages you need to install globally. `pip` and `virtualenv` are examples of packages you need to install globally (that is, with `sudo` or as root). You should avoid to install `django` globally as some apps might need different versions. 2. No, that is not okay - you have installed python drivers globally (I doubt it installed correctly, because you may have missing dependencies). 3. No; that's fine. Just run `virtualenv` as a normal user to create an environment for the Python application you are hosting.

Comment: Since for question 1, I already did not avoid installing the base Python libraries properly. Should I start from scratch? I don't mind since this is just a VM and I really want to make sure I get this right before I move to production.

Comment: Hi Burhan, I am almost there with your answer. I just need a few more clarifications with issues like what exactly do I install as base Python libraries and how to install. Would be great, if you can fill in the gaps on those. Thank you.

Comment: There is actually no need to scrupulously avoid installing non-base packages, since nowadays virtualenv will not copy over site-packages by default.  It is still a good idea to avoid using `sudo pip` under any circumstances though, because one bad package can still ruin everyone's day.

Comment: @ChuckAdams in addition, when you do `sudo pip install` - any bootstrapping scripts for that package will also run with root privileges.

Comment: I am still a bit lost. I took a stab trying out on #python irc. And another person advised to use apt-get install python-virtualenv. This is my latest attempt. https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/1781035db3ee7b6cddc9#file-install-sh-L88 I have also took out all the pip related install lines.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Here are my questions. supervisord install via pip? If I were to install pip, virtualenv, etc, then which version do I install since I want to have 2.7 python environment and a 3.4 python environment for 2 different django apps?

Comment: You install them for both; separately. supervisord you can install with pip for the base version of Python for your system.

Comment: Apologies. I am still confused about this concept of base version of Python. I have reused a blank ubuntu 14.04 virtual box and when i typed `python -V` I get python 2.7.6. Is that my base python? And is it possible to have multiple base versions of Python?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple version of python. To use python 3 with Ubuntu, you have to type `python3`.  
But keep in mind it can be difficult to run two different version of the wsgi connector on the same webserver (at least with apache, you will have a hard time trying to run a version for python 2 and a version for python 3)

Answer (score 2):

**Understanding execution path**

The first principle to understand is that when you install packages on your operating system (virtual machine, whatever) with `sudo` is that you are installing all those packages in a global location, that is, a file directory which your system knows about via the `$PATH` (`PATH`) environment variable.

This `$PATH` variable is often set-up by default in your `.bashrc` or your `.bash_profile` or your `.profile` whenever a new linux/unix user is created.  Whether you have any of these files depends on what is inside the `/etc/skel` on your system.  `/etc/skel` holds a "template" of these files that gets duplicated whenever a new user with a home directory is created.

When you type `echo $PATH` in command line, you would see a list of execution search path delimited by `:`, for example:

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`

This is an example I will use for the purpose of this discussion. Different OS will give you slightly different default `$PATH` but the simple idea here is that the binaries of your globally installed packages gets thrown into one of these directories and the reason you are able to run these binaries is because these binaries (programs) are now available in the execution search path (simply called `$PATH`).

**Ok great, but what does this mean for the python 2 and python 3 interpreters I installed?**

So in relation to your question, this means that when you `sudo apt-get` or `sudo aptitude` install python2 or python3 binaries (python interpreters), they are both available and to differentiate which interpeter you are using at any moment, you would run `python2.7` or `python3.4` that correspondingly calls `/usr/bin/python2.7` or `/usr/bin/python3.4`

You can always check this easily by using the `which` linux/unix command.  `which python3.4` will return you the exact path where your `python3.4` binary is installed.

Similarly, when type `pip2.7` in your command line, you are asking your system to execute the `pip2.7` program that came installed with your `python2.7` package. And naturally `which pip2.7` will reveal to you where this `pip2.7` binary has been installed.

All this is possible simply because these binaries are have been installed by you using `sudo apt-get` and are placed in the directories listed in `$PATH`.  If you move one of these binaries forcibly to another directory not listed in `$PATH`, you will realize that you can no longer run the binary in your command line without typing out the specific path to the binary.

**Additional python specific information**

The Python Interpreter has another attribute call `$PYTHONPATH`.  This - as you will rightly deduce - is a variable that holds a list of directories ("search path") where the *python interpreter will search for python modules to load*.  If you want to know where your python interpreter is currently looking for modules (your own python modules or 3rd party python modules), run

`python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

where `python` is your specific python interpreter.  If `/usr/bin/python` is symlinked to `/usr/bin/python2.7`, then you are in fact calling `python2.7`.

When would python path matter?  It matters inside your own `.py` source code when you ask to `import` other modules.  The `import` line of code in your `.py` source code is where you are asking the python interpreter to go forth and search for the module that you want to import.  As you can imagine, if your `sys.path` (in python) is empty, you will not be able to import any 3rd party modules.

**Beyond the gory details**

Now that we have a clear understanding of the underlying principles behind `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH`, we can now understand what the `virtualenv` (and additionally, `virtualenvwrapper` is useful) does for us.

When we create a new virtualenv giving it a directory, what we are saying is that we want to symlink a specific python interpreter (via `-p python2.7` flag for the virtualenv command) for example to that virtualenv.

When we source activate that virtualenv we created, we are in fact invoking shell scripts that come with virtualenv to dynamically modify the `$PATH`.  Try running `echo $PATH` after you have source activated a virtualenv you created.  What do you see?

That's right, you will be seeing something like this:-

`/Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`

And if you type `which python`, what do you get?

`/Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python`

That's right, the python interpreter we are using is the one that is inside the virtualenv directory and no longer from the `/usr/bin` directory.

If you run

`ls -la /Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin`

what do you see?

Ah! A symlink to the specific global python interpreter you specified when you created this virtualenv.  If you don't see a symlink, this means that your entire python interpreter was copied over from the globally installed one.

So this is what our virtualenv tool does.  It lets us isolate specific projects and choose which python interpreter to use for a specific project.

Once you have source activated a virtualenv, your pip is also the pip that is located in your virtualenv directory.  This pip is python path-aware.  When you issue `pip install` commands, python packages now gets installed into your

`/Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/site-packages`

python packages directory; and are available **ONLY** to your project when you source activate that particular project.

**What if you install packages with `sudo pip`?**

`sudo pip` calls the pip tool that comes with your globally installed python interpreter.  When you use `sudo pip`, you are installing your python packages into a global location (which is not jailed within a virtualenv).

I did not give you specific answers to your how-can-I-make-two-projects-use-two-different-python-interpreters question.  I explained the principles and now that you know the principles, it is clear what you need to do. Cheers!

:D

Answer (score 0):

you should have to try following steps to make your django work with python-2.7.

As Ubuntu-14 already come with Python-2.7 installed. so no need to install python-2.7. 
First of all install python setuptools for python-2.7:

```
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-12.0.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf setuptools-12.0.5.tar.gz
cd setuptools-12.0.5/
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

after install setuptools install pip for python-2.7

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-6.0.8.tar.gz
tar -zxvf pip-6.0.8.tar.gz
cd pip-6.0.8/
sudu python2.7 setup.py install
```

after installing pip now we have to go for install python virtual environment:

```
sudo pip2.7 install virtualenv
```

then to folder where you want to create new virtualenv using python 2.7
virtualenv-2.7 "name for new virtualenv for example '/var/virtual/DjangoProject'" 
cd /var/virtual/

```
virtualenv-2.7 DjangoProject
```

Note just created virtualenv name is "DjangoProject"
Now time to activate new virtualenv

```
cd DjangoProject
source bib/activate
```

Now time to clone your project here.

```
git clone "your git url"
```

install rest of apps and django here. if you have created simply install by requirement.txt

```
cd "projectFolder"
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

after doing all these your new python2.7 django with virtualenv are ready to use. just run django wsgi server for test is every thing working:

```
python manage.py runserver.
```

Now you can use this virtualenv and project to setup for web server.

Hope this will help-full to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) (and [pyenv virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper)). With these  tools you can have multiple Python versions and switch between them.

Here is how you setup one environment with Python 3.4.2 and one with Python 2.7.8 (and each environment can have its own Python packages)

```
# install pyenv
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv

# setup pyenv and load when shell is loaded
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

# install pyenv virtualenvwrapper
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper

# setup pyenv virtualenvwrapper and load when shell is loaded
echo 'export PYENV_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PREFER_PYVENV="true"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo "pyenv virtualenvwrapper" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now everything is setup. Restart your shell.

```
# install python 2.7.8
pyenv install 2.7.8
pyenv rehash

# install python 3.4.2
pyenv install 3.4.2
pyenv rehash

# switch the global python version to 2.7.8
pyenv global 2.7.8

# create a virtual environment using python 2.7.8
mkvirtualenv project278

# -- now you can install you python 2 modules

# leave the virtual environment
deactivate


# switch the global python to 3.4.2
pyenv global 3.4.2

# create a virtual environment using python 3.4.2
mkvirtualenv project342

# -- now you can install you python 2 modules

# leave the virtual environment
deactivate

# switch the global python to the system python.
pyenv global system

# swith to environment project278 and check the python version
workon project278
python --version

# swith to environment project342 and check the python version
workon project342
python --version
```

Voilà! You now have two environments with different Python versions. Just use the `workon` (and the `deactivate`) commands to switch between them.

Make sure you read the documentation of the used packages, so you understand what is going on!